# querydsl CollectionTable joinColumns dto Projections not an entity

Tags: querydsl

I got an error not an entity

I think should create a uri entity
but I want to get the result using CollectionTable annotation

It works without uri in dto

How can I use the uri in dto?

expect query(example)

```sql
select gai.*, gaiu.uri from goose_auth_items gai
join goose_auth_items_uri gaiu on gai.item_identity = gaiu.goose_auth_items_id
where gai.user_identity = 1;
```

**entity**

```java
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(
    name = "goose_auth_items_uri",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "goose_auth_items_id")
)
@Column(name = "uri")
@Builder.Default
private List<String> uri = new ArrayList<>();
```

**QClass**

```java
public final ListPath<String, StringPath> uri = this.<String, StringPath>createList("uri", String.class, StringPath.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);
```

**dto**

```java
private List<String> uri = new ArrayList<>();
```

**query**

```java
return queryFactory.select(
    Projections.constructor(GooseAuthGetItemsResponseDto.class,
        gooseAuthItems.name,
        gooseAuthItems.userName,
        gooseAuthItems.userPassword,
        gooseAuthItems.folder,
        gooseAuthItems.notes,
        gooseAuthItems.uri, <-- not working
        gooseAuthItems.updateDate)
    ).from(gooseAuthItems)
    .where(gooseAuthItems.userMaster.eq(userMaster))
    .fetch();
```

I wanted to use Projections.constructor to get only I needed
I want to uri in the json response body as a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a limitation of JPA, you cannot project plural relationships in a tuple. You have to join them. Then afterwards you have to group the results to combine the various uri elements for each entity.

Comment: thanks for the reply!
I'll try to solve it with jpa

Answer (score 0):

solved this.

I didn't use querydsl. use jpa

Changed from entity to dto.

```
List<GooseAuthItems> gooseAuthItemsList = itemsRepository.findAllByUserMasterAndFolder(userIdentify, folder);
return gooseAuthItemsList.stream()
    .map(gooseAuthItems -> new GooseAuthGetItemsResponseDto(gooseAuthItems.getName(),
        gooseAuthItems.getUserName(),
        gooseAuthItems.getUserPassword(), gooseAuthItems.getUri(), gooseAuthItems.getFolder(),
        gooseAuthItems.getNotes(), gooseAuthItems.getUpdateDate()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```